# Delphi - searching for object in array

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have function to search for TItem (my own class) in array of TItem.

```
function IndexOfArray(const Value: TItem; Things: array of TItem): integer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for i := Low(Things) to High(Things) do
    if Value = Things[i] then
    begin
      Result := i;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

It's working for array of TItem. But I want to use it with TItem or TIamge or TLabel. I tried TObject or TComponent as input parameters of this method, but compiler shouts:

```
E2010 Incompatible types: 'array of TComponent' and 'Dynamic array'
```

The array of TLabel/TImage/TItem MUST be dynamic. Any ideas please?

Comment: What Delphi version do you use?

Comment: I try compile with `const Value: TLabel; Things: array of TLabel` - all ok. Maybe you can show part of code which produce this error?

Comment: Nope, I want to call it like this: `IndexOfArray(LabelLoaded, Labels)` where Labels is dynamic array of TLabel. At another place in program I want to call this: `IndexOfArray(ImageLoaded, Images)` where Images is array of TImage. Do you get it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TArray.BinarySearch](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.BinarySearch) does that for you.

```
if TArray.BinarySearch<TLabel>(Labels,LabelLoaded,index) then
  // Index holds the index of the found item
```

> Note: BinarySearch requires that the array be sorted.

If you just want to compare the pointer value of the objects, here is an example:

```
Type
  TMyArray = record
    class function IndexOfArray<T:Class>(const value: T; const Things: array of T): Integer; static;
  end;

class function TMyArray.IndexOfArray<T>(const value: T; const Things: array of T): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(Things) do
    if value = Things[i] then
      Exit(i);
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Comment: Note: BinarySearch requires that the array be sorted.

Comment: Thank you, it works, I will write solution to my post.

Comment: core, I added an example if you just want to compare the pointer value of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own bicycle you can try something like this:

```
type
    myAr = array of TObject;

. . . 

function IndexOfArray(const Value: TObject; Things: myAr): integer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for i := Low(Things) to High(Things) do
    if (Things[i] is Value.ClassType) and  // don't sure that this is nessesary
       (Value = Things[i]) then
    begin
      Result := i;
      Break;
    end;
end;

procedure someProc;
var
    ar : myAr;
    lbl : TLabel;
    i : integer;
begin
  SetLength(ar, 10);
  for I := Low(ar) to High(ar) do
    ar[i] := TLabel.Create(self);
  lbl := TLabel.Create(Self);
  i := IndexOfArray(lbl, ar);
end;
```

Also you can use standard [`System.Generics.Collections.TArray.BinarySearch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8//en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.BinarySearch) class.

Comment: The `is` check isn't necessary. When followed by an `=` check, as it is here, an `is` check is entirely redundant (and also dangerous if the `TObject` value you happen to search for is `nil`).